# Base de datos no realiza inserts , errno: 1064

Tags: sql, mysqli, postman

Tengo una base de datos de un gimnasio con una tabla llamada 'personas' , el problema es al insertar datos a la tabla mediante un POST con POSTMAN, me aparece el siguiente mensaje en la consola:

[image: Consola]

El codigo para el POST es el siguiente:

```
app.post('/',
(req, res) => {

    let per = req.body;
    var sql = "SET @IdRol = ?;SET @IdTipoDocumento = ?;SET @Apellido = ?;SET @Nombre = ?;SET @Documento = ?;SET @Password = ?;SET @Telefono = ?;SET @Sexo = ?;SET @Observaciones = ?;SET @Foto = ?;SET @FechaNac = ?;SET @Correo = ?;SET @Usuario = ?; \
    CALL bsp_alta_personas(@IdRol,@IdTipoDocumento,@Apellido,@Nombre,@Documento,@Password,@Telefono,@Sexo,@Observaciones,@Foto,@FechaNac,@Correo,@Usuario);";


    con.query(sql, [per.IdRol, per.IdTipoDocumento, per.Apellido, per.Nombre, per.Documento, per.Password, per.Telefono, per.Sexo, per.Observaciones, per.Foto, per.FechaNac, per.Correo, per.Usuario], function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });

    // res.render('mensaje', {
    //     mensaje: 'La carga se efectuo correctamente'
    // });

    res.status(201).json({
        ok: true,
        // usuario: usuarioGuardado
        // usuariotoken: req.usuario
    })

});
```

El JSON enviado es :

[image: JSON]

Comment: ¿Tu sentencia SQL es solo  `SET ...;SET...;...`?  creo que ahí tienes el problema, ese definitivamente no es un código sql válido. ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por la respuesta , pues quiero insertar datos en una tabla como bien dice la pregunta. El SQL tambien llama a un STORE PROCEDURE si te fijas bien  , saludos!